# Printing formatted output using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I used `awk` to generate the following output

```
   root | /root
   bin | /bin
   daemon | /sbin
   adm | /var/adm
   lp | /var/spool/lpd
```

My `awk` query is as follows

```
  head -n 5 /etc/passwd | awk ' BEGIN{ FS=":";OFS=" | "; } { print $1 , $6 } '
```

I want the output to be displayed in a formatted manner as below

```
   root   | /root
   bin    | /bin
   daemon | /sbin
   adm    | /var/adm
   lp     | /var/spool/lpd
```

Is it possible to achieve this using `awk` . Also , the code should work on multiple input fields delimited by `|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try piping your awk result to `column`:

```
awk 'whatever'|column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution will be using printf

```
awk -F: '{printf "%-15s | %s\n",$1,$6}' /etc/passwd
```

note that if you remove `-` sign you can right align the userids as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS=" | " }
FNR<=5 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        wid[i] = (wid[i] > length($i) ? wid[i] : length($i))
        val[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=NR; rowNr++) {
        printf "%-*s | %-*s\n", wid[1], val[rowNr,1], wid[6], val[rowNr,6]
    }
}
```

The above calculates the max width of each field and then uses that when printing to make sure the fields are aligned properly regardless of the contents of your input file(s).